# ArangoDB uniqueVertices global excluding the first and last vertices

Tags: arangodb

I'm attempting to find all unique paths from one friend to another.

When I use uniqueVertices: 'global', it is only returning one path because the end vertices is considered is part of the global unique.

```
FOR v,e,p
IN 1..6
ANY "entities/foo" 
GRAPH "friendGraph"
OPTIONS {
bfs: true,
uniqueVertices: 'path'
}
SORT e.weight ASC
FILTER v._id == "entities/bar"
RETURN p
```

Is there a way to have uniqueVertices: 'global' ignore the end vertices? I know there isn't a way to specifically do that. But is there a way to accomplish the same thing?

'path' resulted in way to many results.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you consider A-B, A-B-C and A-B-C-D to be non-unique if there is also a path A-B-C-D-E? Can you provide a concrete example if you need something else?

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting all connections from A to E. I can't use unique global because it will stop after it gets to E once. However, I don't want to use unique path because there are too many results. So if there was a way to have the same affect of unique global, but ignore the _id in: FILTER v._id == "entities/bar"

Comment: I'm still confused. You say you want to get all connections, which the unique path option seems to accomplish, but on the other hand you don't want all because you say they are too many. It would be helpful if you could provide an example dataset or drawing of a graph to illustrate which paths you want to return and which you don't want.

Comment: Sorry. Let me try to re-word this as best I can. The simplest form of my question is: I want to find all the paths, with "uniqueVertices: 'global'"  from a specific start vertices "foo" to a specific vertices "bar". The only way I know to do that is with "FILTER v._id == "entities/bar"". However, because it's Unique Global, it only allows "entities/bar" once. Thus only giving one result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so you want to get all possible paths between two vertices, not just one shortest path, nor all shortest paths, but really all paths that connect the two nodes? https://i.imgur.com/PPPObro.png Not sure about B (orange), vertices on the paths are unique, but vertices and edges are not unique globally. Even with a weight attribute, you could run in the situation that two edges have identical weights and one has to be chosen at random, making the traversal non-deterministic.

Comment: That would be fine if there's a non-deterministic situation. Do you think there's a query that would do this? That png is exactly what I'm looking for. Except, weighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use globally unique vertices but for the last one, you could add the last step in the path manually like so:

```
FOR v,e,p
IN 0..5
ANY "entities/foo"
GRAPH "friendGraph"
OPTIONS {
    bfs: true,
    uniqueVertices: 'global'
}
FILTER p.vertices[*]._id ALL != "entities/bar"
FOR w,f
IN 1..1
ANY v
GRAPH "friendGraph"
FILTER w._id == "entities/bar"
SORT f.weight ASC
RETURN { edges: APPEND(p.edges, [f]), vertices: APPEND(p.vertices, [w]) }
```

I'd like to note two things:

- the `SORT` operation you added might not achieve what you want: it sorts the paths by the weight of the path's last edge
- this does not find *all* unique paths between the two vertices. For that using the option `uniqueVertices: 'path'` would be correct, and there might well be a lot of them.

Comment: This worked perfect! What is this line doing though? FILTER p.vertices[*]._id ALL != "entities/bar"

Comment: It prevents the first `FOR` operation from returning paths containing the target vertex `"entities/bar"`, which is now reached with the second `FOR` operation.